# How can I loop this functions in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

```
    $( "#transbox1" ).one( "mouseenter", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
$( "#transbox1" ).one( "mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
});
$( "#transbox2" ).one( "mouseenter", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
$( "#transbox2" ).one( "mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
});
$( "#transbox3" ).one( "mouseenter", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
$( "#transbox3" ).one( "mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
});
$( "#transbox4" ).one( "mouseenter", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
$( "#transbox4" ).one( "mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
});
```

I have 4 boxes and with mouseenter the box will grow 200px and whne the mouse leaves the box will get smaller with 200px. How cand I do to do this all the time?

Comment: You can just use the same class on of all of them, no need to loop

Comment: Now are you using `.one()` - event called once then detached - or `.on()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a class to all the elements, then you can use a class selector to address all of them at once:

HTML:

```
<div id"transbox1" class="transbox"></div>
<div id"transbox2" class="transbox"></div>
<div id"transbox3" class="transbox"></div>
...
```

Javascript:

```
$( ".transbox" ).on( "mouseenter", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
$( ".transbox" ).on( "mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
});
```

Comment: Yes but they still do this once.

Comment: Oh yea, I totally missed that. Use `.on()` instead of `.one()`

Answer (score 3):

Just add a class to all of them

```
   <div class="myClass" id="transbox1"></div>

   $( ".myClass" ).on( "mouseenter", function() {
    $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
    $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
   });
  $( ".myClass" ).on( "mouseleave", function() {
    $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
    $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
  });
```

Comment: @indubitablee Are you sure you should be editing `.one` to `.on`? There's a function for both in jQuery.

Comment: And yes, I see that now.

Comment: @TimLewis apologies, you are correct, i assumed that OP wanted an "hover" effect with mouseenter and mouseover (instead of .one). my explanation was more of that maybe it was a typo in that he wanted .on instead of .one

Comment: @indubitablee I know, I had to check that `.one` was actually a function :P But your edit is correct, OP doesn't want a just once, so you can leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
$("div[id^='transbox']").one( "mouseenter", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
$("div[id^='transbox']").one( "mouseleave", function() {
   $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
   $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
});
```

I have assumed that your box is div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a common name or class to all these boxes, then use below code incase they have common Name - **transbox** :

```
$("[name=transbox]" ).one( "mouseenter", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "+=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
$("[name=transbox]" ).one( "mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).css( "width", "-=200" );
  $( this ).css( "height", "-=200" );
});
```